# How does this isolation circuit work?

Tags: transistors, dc, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to understand how this isolation circuit works (in the red box):

[image]

It uses an optocoupler, but how does it work?

The signal RC2 is this
[image]

Why is the input of the optocoupler connected between VCC1 and RC2, With VCC1 is 5v+ what's the purpose of this configuration?.

Comment: well, the purpose of something results in from where it's used. Since VCC1 is explicitly *not* called +5 in your schematic, it's fair to assume they are at least not directly connected; obviously, the purpose of this circuit is to protect the right side from things on the left side, which probably are not the "normal" operation shown in your diagram. – but you already know that. You'll need to offer more context here.

Comment: Controlling input of optocoupler is based on grounding of RC2 what makes  pulling base of Q2 to ground, closing Q1 and discharge the Gate of Mosfet thru Q4 to 0.7V.  D1 is reverse biased in this state.

Comment: Why is your signal diagram labelled VGS? If it had a label shouldn't it be RC2? Engineering is about checking the details in case you were unaware.

Answer (score 3):

The schematic symbol is a bit sketchy for the [OPI-8015](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/r3u7qhxggx/TXIIS190987-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw).

It is a part containing an infrared LED and an IC which has a photodiode and output circuitry to provide a logic-level output.

[image]

When the LED has sufficient current flowing through it the photodiode provides a signal to exceed the threshold of the Schmitt trigger and the output switches.

There is no electrical connection between the LED and the rest of the circuitry within the OPI8015 package- so the OPI8015 component itself is what provides the actual (opto)isolation.

The circuitry shown following the isolator is a level shifter (Q2) to +12V and high-side driver (Q1) with active pull-down (Q4/D1).

Answer (score -1):

This circuit can be thought of as a common base , (CB) current buffer for TTL logic such that it can pull down a 12V logic load with an emitter follower with 33R in series with the output with ground voltage noise isolation.

**Choosing the hi-side or lo-side for driving the LED is a matter of preference for inverting or non-inverting logic.**

“ An optocoupler (also called optoisolator) is a semiconductor device that allows an electrical signal to be transmitted between two isolated circuits. Two parts are used in an optocoupler: an LED that emits infrared light and a photosensitive device that detects light from the IR Emitter LED.”

The input is a current limited by R and the voltage difference I=V/R between VCC1 and Vf=1.2V min for the LED. You can drive it from the high side with pin 2 towards 0V with the R in series on either side of pin 1 or 2. Or as shown, drive it from the low side, pin 2 to 0V with the high side fixed to VCC1. This allows you to use any logic or open collector switch to drive the cathode on pin 2 and thus makes the voltage levels non-inverting from input to output.

Either way this current emits Infrared light inside the IC towards the base of a transistor which exposed to this light will conduct current sufficiently to saturate as a switch, albeit with low current transfer ratio (CTR) often <1 even with the Beta or hFE of the transistor.

Transistors have a property that hFE drops towards 10 % of its max. when saturated as a low coltage switch on the output for Vce=Vce(sat) < 0.5V which is partly why the IC has low CTR.

The insulation inside the chip between the IR emitter and transistor detector is such that it will not conduct current guaranteed up to it’s specified rating which depending on the chip may be from 1200 to 5000 V. This also requires the PCB to have an air gap under and around the IC to prevent dust and high voltage from bypassing this dielectric breakdown arc suppression when stressed  with high voltage connected to say the grid or electrostatic charge voltage.

An optocoupler also prevents supply or ground voltage from being shared between source and load.  We call this common-mode noise rejection  by isolating the ground or supply from interfering with the output even if there is no need for high voltage protection with this photon coupling rather than conduction.

There are many different configurations of “Opto’s” and this IC is designed for logic with hysteresis to ensure the output is On or OFF without a linear uncertain current output in between.